# How can I save all the input of the opening hours in a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a Bootstrap modal to ask the user for the opening hours of their restaurant. The problem is that I couldn't afford to save the inputs correctly in a variable. At the moment it saves the times double, when the user isn't clicking the checkbox. If I add another row, it saves four times the first rows. The checkbox works properly.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var openingHours = {};
  const days = [
    "Montag",
    "Dienstag",
    "Mittwoch",
    "Donnerstag",
    "Freitag",
    "Samstag",
    "Sonntag",
  ];

  days.forEach((day) => {
    const dayRow = document.createElement("div");
    dayRow.classList.add(
      "form-group",
      "flex-column",
      "col-12",
      "py-2",
      "m-2",
      "dayGroup",
      "border-bottom",
      "d-flex",
      "flex-md-row"
    );
    dayRow.innerHTML = `
  <div class="col-md-4 col-12 row">
    <div class="col-6 font-weight-bold align-top">${
      day.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + day.slice(1)
    }</div>
    <div class="col-6 align-top">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="${day}" id="${day}Checkbox">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="${day}Checkbox">Geschlossen</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-md-6 col-12 mt-3 mt-md-0" id="${day}Times">
    <div class="col-12 row mb-3">
      <div class="col-6">
        <label for="${day}StartTime">Starzeit:</label>
        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="${day}StartTime" name="${day}StartTime" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <label for="${day}EndTime">Endzeit:</label>
        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="${day}EndTime" name="${day}EndTime" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttoncontainer">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary addTime" data-day="${day}" title="Hier klicken um weitere Zeilen hinzuzufügen">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger removeTime d-none mt-3" title="Hier klicken um die Zeilen zu entfernen" data-day="${day}">-</button>
    </div>
  </div>
`;
    document.getElementById("openingHoursForm").appendChild(dayRow);

    const closedCheckbox = document.getElementById(`${day}Checkbox`);
    closedCheckbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
      const isChecked = this.checked;
      const timeInputs = document.querySelectorAll(`#${day}Times input`);
      timeInputs.forEach((input) => (input.disabled = isChecked));
    });

    const addTimeButton = document.querySelector(`.addTime[data-day="${day}"]`);
    addTimeButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const day = e.target.getAttribute("data-day");
      const timeGroup = document.getElementById(`${day}Times`);
      const rowCount = timeGroup.getElementsByClassName("row").length;

      if (rowCount < 3) {
        const newRow = document.createElement("div");
        newRow.classList.add("col-12", "row", "mb-3");
        newRow.innerHTML = `
      <div class="col-6">
        <label for="${day}StartTime">Starzeit:</label>
        <input type="time" class="form-control" name="${day}StartTime" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <label for="${day}EndTime">Endzeit:</label>
        <input type="time" class="form-control" name="${day}EndTime" value="">
      </div>
    `;

        timeGroup.appendChild(newRow);
        updateRemoveButton(day);
      }
    });

    const removeTimeButton = document.querySelector(
      `.removeTime[data-day="${day}"]`
    );
    removeTimeButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const day = e.target.getAttribute("data-day");
      const timeGroups = document.querySelectorAll(`#${day}Times .row`);
      const rowCount = timeGroups.length;

      if (rowCount > 1) {
        const lastRow = timeGroups[timeGroups.length - 1];
        lastRow.remove();
        updateRemoveButton(day);
      }
    });
  });

  function updateRemoveButton(day) {
    const timeGroups = document.querySelectorAll(`#${day}Times .row`);
    const removeButton = document.querySelector(
      `.removeTime[data-day="${day}"]`
    );
    if (timeGroups.length > 1) {
      removeButton.classList.remove("d-none");
    } else {
      removeButton.classList.add("d-none");
    }
  }

  document
    .getElementById("Speichern")
    .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      days.forEach((day) => {
        const timeInputs = document.querySelectorAll(`#${day}Times input`);
        const timeRanges = [];

        timeInputs.forEach((inputGroup) => {
          const startTimeElement = document.getElementById(`${day}StartTime`);
          const endTimeElement = document.getElementById(`${day}EndTime`);

          const startTime = startTimeElement.value;
          const endTime = endTimeElement.value;

          if (startTime && endTime) {
            timeRanges.push({ begin: startTime, ende: endTime });
          }
        });

        openingHours[day.toLowerCase()] =
          timeRanges.length > 0 ? timeRanges : "Geschlossen";
      });

      const formattedOpeningHours = JSON.stringify(openingHours, null, 2);
      document.getElementById("ausgabe").textContent = formattedOpeningHours;
      document.getElementById("openhours_2").value = formattedOpeningHours;
      $("#openhours").modal("hide");
    });

  document
    .getElementById("openModalButton")
    .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#openhours").modal("show");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="opening_hours">Öffnungszeiten:</label><br />
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    id="openhours_2"
    name="openhours_2"
    value=""
    hidden
  />
  <button
    class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"
    onclick="location.href='#'"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#openhours"
    id="openModalButton"
  >
    Hier klicken zum Eintragen
  </button>
  <br />
  <p id="ausgabe"></p>
  <div
    class="modal fade"
    id="openhours"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="attributeLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="attributeLabel">Öffnungszeiten</h5>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="close"
            data-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
          >
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container mt-5">
            <div id="openingHoursForm" style="margin-top: -25px">
              <!-- Here the form is renderd -->
            </div>
            <button id="Speichern" class="btn btn-success mt-3" id="openbutton">
              Speichern
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example output (I chose Monday-Saturday the checkbox and two different times for Sunday):

```json
{
  "montag": "Geschlossen",
  "dienstag": "Geschlossen",
  "mittwoch": "Geschlossen",
  "donnerstag": "Geschlossen",
  "freitag": "Geschlossen",
  "samstag": "Geschlossen",
  "sonntag": [
    { "begin": "12:00", "ende": "18:00" },
    { "begin": "12:00", "ende": "18:00" },
    { "begin": "12:00", "ende": "18:00" },
    { "begin": "12:00", "ende": "18:00" }
  ]
}
```

I tried to debug with Inspector, ChatGPT, and other tools for a while, but nothing has worked.

Comment: I'm afraid you're paragraph is very confusing. Can you please clarify? If English is not your first language, do you have someone who could help you?

Comment: To put it in a nutshell I want to ask the user in the modal to type in the open hours. The form has the option to add a maximum of 3 different hours, because a restaurant could open and close more than one time a day. I want to save the user input in a variable to save it in my database. In the moment, when I am pushing the save button and I input 12:00 - 18:00, it gets saved double in the array. If I add 2 rows for a day, it gets saved four times in the array. I just want to save it one time for each time range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as a sample set.

Unfortunately i dont have the modal code.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var openingHours = {};
  const days = ["Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag"];

  days.forEach((day) => {
    const dayRow = document.createElement("div");
    dayRow.classList.add("form-group", "flex-column", "col-12", "py-2", "m-2", "dayGroup", "border-bottom", "d-flex", "flex-md-row");
    dayRow.innerHTML = `<div class="col-md-4 col-12 row">
    <div class="col-6 font-weight-bold align-top">${day}</div>
    <div class="col-6 align-top">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="${day}" id="${day}Checkbox">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="${day}Checkbox">Geschlossen</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-md-6 col-12 mt-3 mt-md-0" id="${day}Times">
    <div class="col-12 row mb-3">
      <div class="col-6">
        <label for="${day}StartTime0">Starzeit:</label>
        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="${day}StartTime0" name="${day}StartTime0" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <label for="${day}EndTime0">Endzeit:</label>
        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="${day}EndTime0" name="${day}EndTime0" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttoncontainer">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary addTime" data-day="${day}" title="Hier klicken um weitere Zeilen hinzuzufügen">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger removeTime d-none mt-3" title="Hier klicken um die Zeilen zu entfernen" data-day="${day}">-</button>
    </div>
  </div>`;
    document.getElementById("openingHoursForm").appendChild(dayRow);

    const closedCheckbox = document.getElementById(`${day}Checkbox`);
    closedCheckbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
      const isChecked = this.checked;
      const timeInputs = document.querySelectorAll(`#${day}Times input`);
      timeInputs.forEach((input) => (input.disabled = isChecked));
    });

    const addTimeButton = document.querySelector(`.addTime[data-day="${day}"]`);
    addTimeButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const day = e.target.getAttribute("data-day");
      const timeGroup = document.getElementById(`${day}Times`);
      const rowCount = timeGroup.getElementsByClassName("row").length;

      if (rowCount < 3) {
        const newRow = document.createElement("div");
        newRow.classList.add("col-12", "row", "mb-3");
        newRow.innerHTML = `<div class="col-6">
            <label for="${day}StartTime${rowCount}">Starzeit:</label>
            <input type="time" class="form-control" id="${day}StartTime${rowCount}" name="${day}StartTime${rowCount}" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <label for="${day}EndTime${rowCount}">Endzeit:</label>
            <input type="time" class="form-control" id="${day}EndTime${rowCount}" name="${day}EndTime${rowCount}" value="">
          </div>`;
        timeGroup.appendChild(newRow);
        updateRemoveButton(day);
      }
    });

    const removeTimeButton = document.querySelector(`.removeTime[data-day="${day}"]`);
    removeTimeButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const day = e.target.getAttribute("data-day");
      const timeGroups = document.querySelectorAll(`#${day}Times .row`);
      const rowCount = timeGroups.length;

      if (rowCount > 1) {
        const lastRow = timeGroups[timeGroups.length - 1];
        lastRow.remove();
        updateRemoveButton(day);
      }
    });
  });

  function updateRemoveButton(day) {
    const timeGroups = document.querySelectorAll(`#${day}Times .row`);
    const removeButton = document.querySelector(`.removeTime[data-day="${day}"]`);
    if (timeGroups.length > 1) {
      removeButton.classList.remove("d-none");
    } else {
      removeButton.classList.add("d-none");
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("Speichern").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    days.forEach((day) => {
      const timeInputs = document.querySelectorAll(`#${day}Times input`);
      const timeRanges = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < timeInputs.length; i += 2) {
        const startTime = timeInputs[i].value;
        const endTime = timeInputs[i + 1].value;

        if (startTime && endTime) {
          timeRanges.push({ begin: startTime, ende: endTime });
        }
      }
      openingHours[day.toLowerCase()] = timeRanges.length > 0 ? timeRanges : "Geschlossen";
    });

    const formattedOpeningHours = JSON.stringify(openingHours, null, 2);
    document.getElementById("ausgabe").textContent = formattedOpeningHours;
    document.getElementById("openhours_2").value = formattedOpeningHours;
    $("#openhours").modal("hide");
  });

  document.getElementById("openModalButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#openhours").modal("show");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="opening_hours">Öffnungszeiten:</label><br />
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="openhours_2" name="openhours_2" value="" hidden>
  <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" onclick="location.href='#'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#openhours" id="openModalButton">Hier klicken zum Eintragen</button>
  <br />
  <p id="ausgabe"></p>
  <div class="modal fade" id="openhours" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="attributeLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="attributeLabel">Öffnungszeiten</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container mt-5">
            <div id="openingHoursForm" style="margin-top: -25px"></div>
            <button id="Speichern" class="btn btn-success mt-3">Speichern</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: Explanation of what was wrong.

`days` variable was not defined as per the error message cause of the scope. It usually happens if you define `days` within the scope and then try and use it outside.

To fix this, i made `days` into a global variable accessible by `DOMContentLoaded` event handler.

Comment: What did you change? Where was the mistake? Thank you very much!